# How to pass data in template in angular 2?

Tags: angular

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../../login/services/login.service';
import {User,SharedService} from '../../SharedService'
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        You are logged in! <span>{{ this.user.email }} </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 `
})
export class LogsComponent {

 user:User;

 constructor(ss:SharedService){
   this.user=ss.getUserDetail();
 }



}
```

Because im using laravel and its `{{}}` templating like angular i need to create template in angular and pass data. What i want is to display in template data from this.user.email in my template. Any suggestion how can i do that? Right now its blank..but when i display in `console log this.user` i get object of user.

When i `console.log(this.user)` i get this:

```
object isLoggedIn: trueuser: Object created_at: "2017-03-14 09:04:42"email: "user@user.com"id: 4name: "user"updated_at: "2017-03-14 09:04:42"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

But when i do this : `console.log(this.user.email)` i got undefined.

This is my sharedService:

```
import {Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class User{
 email:string;
 name:string;
}

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  user:User;
  setUserDetail(res){
   this.user=res;
  }
  getUserDetail(){
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

Comment: change `{{ this.user.email }}` to `{{ user.email }}`, you don't need to tell the template that you are refering to the "this", since it is automatically injected.

Comment: i tried that but its blank..i dont get anyhting

Comment: mind telling what **ss.getUserDetail()** is returning? (the object keys)

Comment: Are you sure that **user** isn't empty?

Comment: i updated my question now

Comment: It's weird, `this.user` seem to be correct and contains an `email`field. so `console.log(this.user.email)` should display the email. Where are you calling console.log ?

Comment: in constructor..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access to data in object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858940/how-to-access-to-data-in-object)

Comment: We seem to have a mysterious case of duplicate user accounts ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858940/how-to-access-to-data-in-object

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u r returning an array or JSON that make a difference if u returning JSON make sure that your response are converted into JSON using method res.JSON()
and if u returning Array of Object then it show shows as u see access it like an array...

//this is ur service

```
     getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }
```

//this how u access the data

```
heroes: Hero[];
  constructor (private heroService: HeroService) {}
  ngOnInit() { this.getHeroes(); }
  getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
                     .subscribe(
                       heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Comment: Where i need to do that?

Comment: well look at service return type...what is return type??

Comment: setUserData(data: any): void { this.userData = data; }
    getUserData(): any { return this.userData; }

But if i say return this.userData.json() i get an error

Comment: i updated my question where i use sharedService to set data

Comment: u using web service or demo data??

Comment: im using laravel as backend ... where i send data from database

Comment: im not getting data from url...im getting data from response

Comment: try this solution then i hope it helpfull