# How to access to data in object?

Tags: angular

When i `console.log(this.user)` i get this:

```
Object
isLoggedIn
:
true
user
:
Object
created_at
:
"2017-03-14 09:04:42"
email
:
"user@user.com"
id
:
4
name
:
"user"
updated_at
:
"2017-03-14 09:04:42"
```

But when i now to try to access this.data.email i get undefined. Any suggestion how can i get email from this object?

Because in my template i want do something like this:

```
  <div class="panel-body">
         You are logged in! <span>{{ user.email }} </span>

   </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried console.log(this.data.user.email)?

Comment: Either your object is stringified or @PetrAdam is right :)

Comment: i tried this.data.user.email and this.user.email nothing is working

Comment: if you get full object in this.user than in your html you can write {{ user.user.email }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's gonna work for you, but try this in your html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    You are logged in! <span>{{ user.user.email }} </span>
</div>
```